# ASP MVC3 view model losing data from collection objects on post back to edit method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, postback, viewmodel

My ASP MVC3 view model works just fine with the Edit method loads this particular page, however when the user hits save and does a postback, all information contained in the two collection objects (`List<T>`) is lost. Any ideas?

Here is the code from the view. This loads all agent information (ID and state code) properly

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Fixed.Count; i++)
    {           

        if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Fixed[i].AgentId))
        {
           fixedRow++;

           if (fixedRow > 2)
           {
               var rowId = "row" + fixedRow.ToString() + "F";
               <tr id=rowId class="noSee">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Fixed[i].StateCode,
                         (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList, Model.Fixed[i].StateCode)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fixed[i].AgentId)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fixed[i].AgentId)
                    </td>
                    @if(fixedRow > 1)
                    {
                        var send = "MoreFixed(" + (fixedRow + 1).ToString() + ");";
                        var dataId = "plus" + fixedRow.ToString() + "F;";
                        <td id=@dataId  class="more" onclick=@send>+</td>
                    }
               </tr> 
           }
           else
           {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Fixed[i].StateCode,
                         (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList, Model.Fixed[i].StateCode)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fixed[i].AgentId)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fixed[i].AgentId)
                    </td>
                    @if(fixedRow > 1)
                    {
                        var send = "MoreFixed(" + (fixedRow + 1).ToString() + ");";
                        var id = "plus" + fixedRow.ToString() + "F;";
                        <td id=@id class="more" onclick=@send>+</td>
                    }

                </tr> 
           }        
        }
    }
```

Here is the code from the view model

```
public class BankListViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string Tier { get; set; }
    public string SpecialNotes { get; set; }
    public string WelcomLetterReq { get; set; }

    public List<BankListAgentId> Fixed { get; set; }
    public List<BankListAgentId> Variable { get; set; }
    public List<BankListAttachments> Attachments { get; set; }

    public BankListViewModel()
    {
        //Initialize Fixed and Variable stat Lists
        Fixed = new List<BankListAgentId>();
        Variable = new List<BankListAgentId>();

        Models.BankListAgentId agentId = new BankListAgentId();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Fixed.Add(agentId);
            Variable.Add(agentId);                
        }

        //Initialize attachment Lists
        Attachments = new List<BankListAttachments>();
        Attachments.Add(new BankListAttachments());
    }
}
```

This is the controller method that receives the post back. Again, when the page loads, the 
`GET` Edit method collects all the proper information from the database and returns the view model to the view corretly.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(BankListViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<BankListAgentId> agentId = new List<BankListAgentId>();
            List<BankListAttachments> attachments = new List<BankListAttachments>();
            BankListMaster master = new BankListMaster();

            master = decipherViewModel(viewModel, out agentId, out attachments);

            db.Entry(master).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ID = new SelectList(db.BankListAgentId, "ID", "FixedOrVariable", viewModel.ID);
        return View(viewModel);
    } 

    private BankListMaster decipherViewModel(BankListViewModel viewModel, out List<BankListAgentId> agentId, out List<BankListAttachments> attachments)    
    {
        //Initialize
        BankListMaster banklistmaster = new BankListMaster();
        agentId = new List<BankListAgentId>();
        attachments = new List<BankListAttachments>();

        viewModel.BankName = banklistmaster.BankName;
        viewModel.SpecialNotes = banklistmaster.SpecialNotes;
        viewModel.Tier = banklistmaster.Tier;

        foreach (var item in viewModel.Fixed)
        {
            item.ID = viewModel.ID;
            agentId.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in viewModel.Variable)
        {
            item.ID = viewModel.ID;
            agentId.Add(item); 
        }

        foreach (var item in viewModel.Attachments)
        {
            item.ID = viewModel.ID;
            attachments.Add(item);
        }

        return banklistmaster;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to read values for those collections.

Comment: oops, sorry about that. edited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only things that get posted back to the controller are Html form fields fields.  That's it.  If you do not place the information in a form field (input, select, textarea, etc..) then it will not be posted back.

If you want that data posted back, then you will have to place it in hidden fields.  It is probably easier to simply look that data up in the database on postback.

Answer (score 1):

Those values do not get submitted back to the controller. What gets submitted is the selection from the drop down you created in the view using the values from collections, given that the dropdowns are within the form that you re submitting.

Comment: Both Fixed[i].AgentId/StateCode are missing. All value, not just those from the drop down items, are gone.